# How do I write above a left-right arrow?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

There are a few articles on how to do this for left arrow or right arrow but the method doesn't work for `\leftrightarrow`.

What I want is to write a `\longleftrightarrow` with “DFT” above it.

I've tried:

```
\longleftrightarrow{\text{DFT}}
\longleftrightarrow^{DFT}
\xlongleftrightarrow{\text{DFT}}
\longleftrightarrow\limits^{DFT}
```

None has worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define an extensible "leftright arrow" by the method explained in Section 38 in `Mathmode.pdf` by Herber Voß. You can read it with `texdoc mathmode` on your machine or via [this link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 9999{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\longleftrightarrowfill@{%
  \arrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$F \xleftrightarrow{\text{DFT}} G$

$F \xleftrightarrow{\text{overlong text}} G$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument to `\xleftrightarrow` is for a "under label", so `\xleftrightarrow[xyz]{}` will have `xyz` under the arrow, while `\xleftrightarrow[xyz]{abc}` will have `abc` over and `xyz` under the arrow.

Comment: They are already provided by `mathtools` ;-)

Answer (score 23):

```
\stackrel{\mathrm{DFT}}{\longleftrightarrow}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{extarrows} 

\begin{document}
    $$\xleftrightarrow{DFT}$$ % mathtools
    $$\xlongleftrightarrow{DFT}$$ % extarrows
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to do it is with the function `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{extarrows} 

\begin{document}
    $$\overset{DFT}{\longleftrightarrow}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]