# Text with labeled leftrightarrow under it

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, arrows

I'm trying to get a leftrightarrow under a chunk of text with text centered under each arrow so it would look something like this

```
v = (0 1 ... 1 0 ... 0)
       <-----> <----->
          n       p
```

I've tried

```
\begin{array}{lccr}
v = (0 & \underleftrightarrow{1 \cdots 1} & \underleftrightarrow{0 \cdots 0} &) \\
       & p & n &
\end{array}
```

But I find there is not enough vertical space between `1 ... 1` and the arrow, but there is too much space between the arrow and `p`. Also, the horizontal spacing is uneven.

---

The spacing here is rather better

```
\begin{align*}
v = (0\ & 1 \cdots 1\ 0 \cdots 0) \\
& \overleftrightarrow{\phantom{1 \cdots 1}}\ \overleftrightarrow{\phantom{0 \cdots 0}} 
\end{align*}
```

but then I don't know how to attach text under the arrows.

---

[Writing text over a `\leftrightarrow`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96549/63689) doesn't cut it for me, since I want the `v = etc` to be aligned to the rest of the line with the arrow underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I create `\myarrow` in the syntax of `\xleftrightarrow`, execpt using stacks to accomplish it. (currently only works in `\displaystyle`, if that is OK)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,mathtools}
\newcommand\myarrow[2][]{%
  \setstackEOL{\\}%
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle #1$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\displaystyle #2$}%
  \ensurestackMath{%
    \Longunderstack{#2 \\ \xleftrightarrow[\rule{\wd2}{0pt}]{\rule{\wd0}{0pt}} \\ #1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
v = \{ 0 \myarrow[n]{1 \dots 1} \myarrow[p]{0 \dots 0}\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wants less overhang of the arrows...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,mathtools}
\newcommand\myarrow[2][]{%
  \setstackEOL{\\}%
  \setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle #1$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\displaystyle #2$}%
  \ensurestackMath{%
    \Longunderstack{#2 \\ \xleftrightarrow[\rule{\dimexpr\wd2-4pt}{0pt}]{%
                                           \rule{\dimexpr\wd0-4pt}{0pt}} \\ #1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
v = \{ 0 \myarrow[n]{1 \dots 1} \myarrow[p]{0 \dots 0}\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with `pstricks`. For `pdflatex`, don't forget to `--enable-write 18`\ (MiKTeX) or to `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

  \begin{postscript}
\[ v = (0\ &\pnode(0, -1ex){a}{1} \cdots 1 \pnode(0, -1ex){b}\ \pnode (0, -1ex){c}0\cdots 0\pnode(0, -1ex){d})
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\psset{linewidth=0.4pt, arrows=<->, arrowinset=0.2, shortput=nab, labelsep = 0.5ex}
\ncline{a}{b}_{n}
\ncline{c}{d}_{p}
 \] 
 \end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]