# How to merge two harpoon arrows together?

Tags: arrows, stacking-symbols

I want to merge a `\leftharpoondown` and a `\rightharpoonup` together perfectly, no text necessary. [Left/right harpoon arrow with text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454010/144577) provided some solutions, but each arrowhead has some of the arrowtail of the other arrow jutting out, unfortunately (because the head tapers while the tail has thickness).

Comment: `Mathabx` has a `\leftrightharpoon` and a `\rightleftharpoon` symbols.

Comment: This symbol is Unicode U+204B and is defined by `unicode-math` as `\leftrightharpoondownup`.  I'm not sure whether it's extensible, but might be worth trying.

Comment: @barbarabeeton can you demonstrate how to import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to borrow these symbols from `mathabx` without changing all your symbols:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{%
<-6> matha5
<6-7> matha6
<7-8> mathb7
<8-9> mathb8
<9-10> mathb9
<10-12> mathb10
<12-> mathb12
}{}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}%

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftrightharpoon}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"E0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightleftharpoon}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"E1}

\begin{document}

\[ a \leftrightharpoon b \rightleftharpoon c \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]