# Just use some symbols of one package

Tags: fonts, symbols

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562237/6880), it is shown how to build a new symbol using some symbols of one package. To be honest, I don't understand this post.

I would like to only use the symbols `\leftleftharpoonsrel` and `\rightrightharpoons` of the package `mathabx`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use the same code, and replace the last two lines with `\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftleftharpoons}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"D8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightrightharpoon}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"D9}`

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. How do you find the hexadecimal values D9 and D8 ?

Comment: @egreg See the question above.

Comment: @projetmbc: Just looking at the table for `mathb` in the documentation, p. 19 (it's not as simple for all font packages…).

Comment: @Bernard What are the changes to do so as to use some symbols of the table in the page 18 of the documentation? I can open a new question if you think this is relevant.

Comment: First check the category of the symbols (`mathrel, mathbin,…`)  and the font it belongs to (`matha,mathb,mathx`), then see from the tables their hexadecimal code (indicated with the prefix `"`). The rest  of the code is unchanged, as far as I remember, at least for non-delimiters.

Comment: The following answer of egreg makes it easy to do. Just replace `mathb` by `matha` and this will do the job. Thanks for all.

Comment: This answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217986/standard-ams-sum-operator-using-mnsymbols/219282#219282, helps you in figuring out D8 and D8.  It helps to use `fonttable` to print out the font map, which tells you that information.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Very useful. Thanks for this link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You look in the file `mathabx.dcl` for `\leftleftharpoons` and `\rightrightharpoons` to find

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftleftharpoons}      {3}{mathb}{"D8}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightrightharpoons}    {3}{mathb}{"D9}
```

Now you know that you need the font called `mathb`, which you find in `mathabx.sty`

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
```

I suggest to make the fonts fully scalable at all sizes, so the complete code becomes

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftleftharpoons}      {\mathrel}{mathb}{"D8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightrightharpoons}    {\mathrel}{mathb}{"D9}
```

(the `\hyphenchar` declaration is useless).

I changed `{3}` into `\mathrel` that's clearer about the role of the symbols (however the two styles are equivalent).

Comment: Can I edit your answer to ad the use of a `matha` symbol ?

Comment: @projetmbc Why? There's no mention of it in the question. So first edit the question and I can edit my answer.

Comment: This is related to one of my comments above about the use of `matha`. This is easy to do but it can help other people reading this answer.

Comment: @projetmbc It's exactly the same whether the symbol is in `matha`, `mathb`, `mathc` or `mathx`.

Comment: Ok I will put it just as a comment to my comment. Thanks for all !