# Single Symbols from `mathabx` placed below the line

Tags: fonts, symbols, amsmath, mathabx

I'm using `\usepackage{amssymb}` in my LaTeX document, but I need a few symbols from the `mathabx`. I have followed these posts [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585271/just-use-some-symbols-of-one-package) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622468/how-do-i-import-these-three-specific-symbols-from-mathabx) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633631/how-to-use-the-symbol-blackdiamond-from-the-mathabx-package-without-changing-t) to do so.

When using symbols from `mathb` everything works fine. But when using symbols from `mathx`, the symbols are placed below the line. As shown in the image.

How do I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftleftharpoons}      {\mathrel}{mathb}{'302}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathx5
  <5.5-6.5> mathx6
  <6.5-7.5> mathx7
  <7.5-8.5> mathx8
  <8.5-9.5> mathx9
  <9.5-11> mathx10
  <11-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rvvs}      {\mathrel}{mathx}{'232}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rvvb}      {\mathrel}{mathx}{'252}

\begin{document}

Test test test $a \leftleftharpoons b$. Test test test.

\vspace{1cm}


Test test test $\bigvee_S$. Test test test. 

\vspace{1cm}

Test test test $\rvvs_{S}$. Test test test.

\vspace{1cm}

Test test test $\rvvb_{S}$. Test test test. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's normal, I'm afraid. It would be the same with all “big” symbols from `cmex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. The “big“ variants for symbols are not meant to be called by slot, but by metric font file features. For some (serious) reasons, Knuth decided that these “big” variants should hang from the baseline.

You need to vertically center them manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftleftharpoons}{\mathrel}{mathb}{'302}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathx5
  <5.5-6.5> mathx6
  <6.5-7.5> mathx7
  <7.5-8.5> mathx8
  <8.5-9.5> mathx9
  <9.5-11> mathx10
  <11-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rvvssym}{\mathrel}{mathx}{'232}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rvvbsym}{\mathrel}{mathx}{'252}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rvvs}{}{\mathxbig{\rvvssym}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rvvb}{}{\mathxbig{\rvvbsym}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathxbig}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette\mathxbig@{#1}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\mathxbig@}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test test test $a \leftleftharpoons b$. Test test test.

\vspace{1cm}

Test test test $\bigvee_S$. Test test test. 

\vspace{1cm}

Test test test $\rvvs_{S}$. Test test test.

\vspace{1cm}

Test test test $\rvvb_{S}$. Test test test. 

\end{document}
```

[image]