# How to add text to the \leftrightharpoons symbol in equations?

Tags: equations, symbols, text-decorations, text-manipulation, relation-symbols

Following directly on from the question [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454010/left-right-harpoon-arrow-with-text/651690#651690"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454010/left-right-harpoon-arrow-with-text/651690#651690%22) and referring to the images below (@egreg's image in the referenced answer), I'm just wondering if this can be done with `\leftrightharpoons`?

[image: Egreg's photo]

How can I put text above the `\leftrightharpoons` which can be made as long as the harpoons without compromising the visual appeal of it (i.e. by not having the width of the text longer or shorter than the double harpoons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "mathtools" package

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    $$ A \xleftrightharpoons[abcde]{fghij}B$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for that, exactly what I needed! :)