# mathtools \xleftrightarrow command does not centre text

Tags: amsmath, arrows, mathtools

I would like to have text (maybe a bullet, maybe something else) *above* a left-right arrow, I would also like that text to be *centred*. I would also like the arrow to grow with the text.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$a \xleftrightarrow{x} b$

\end{document}
```

I tried [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96555/78634) but it produces results similar to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `\xleftrightarrow` is wrong.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\xleftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 5599\MT_leftrightarrow_fill: {#1}{#2}}
\makeatother\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathpalette\bbx{#1}}
\newcommand{\bbx}[2]{{\fboxsep=-0.05pt\fboxrule=0.1pt\fbox{$#1#2$}}}

\begin{document}

$a \xleftrightarrow{\bb{x}} b$

\end{document}
```

The macro `\bb` is just used for showing the bounding box of the label, you don't need it.

[image]

Comment: You mean, the definition from `mathtools`?!

Comment: @Sigur Yes, indeed.

Comment: Interesting, I'll compare and study both.

Comment: @egreg this is perfect - thank you!